# how to use MD5 in jetty jersey rest web app

Tags: authentication, jetty, jersey, md5

Can some provide me some help, how to use MD5 authentication in jersey rest web app running on jetty server. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If you mean digest authentication you could start by adding something like this to your `web.xml`:

```xml
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>Secured Services</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>admin</role-name>
        <role-name>user</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>
<login-config>
    <auth-method>DIGEST</auth-method>
    <realm-name>Web Services</realm-name>
</login-config>
<security-role>
    <role-name>admin</role-name>
</security-role>
<security-role>
    <role-name>user</role-name>
</security-role>
```

Then configure your realms using Jetty: http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Tutorial/Realms